# How to deploy many applications on Tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a server where is running my web-application, located in the root folder (you can see it in the image, the path is **/**).
I reach that application by typing the IP and the Port (for example **111.222.333.444:1234**).

Now I'm trying to deploy another web-application and reach it by typing **111.222.333.444:1234/prova/index.jsp** (you can see it in the image, the path is **/prova**).

By using **Tomcat Web Application Manager** I uploaded a new war file called prova.war.

But, when I try to start it by clicking the start button, it doesn't start. In fact, when I click the start button, the **Tomcat Web Application Manager** I get the message:

> FAIL - Application at context path /prova could not be started

.

If I use a ftp client, I can see that prova.war was correctly (I assume) unpacked.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Make sure that deployment was correctly done. No errors in catalina.out

Comment: check the logs... there must be some error while deploying to tomcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the log file. I.e you can check catalina.out file may be there are some issues while deploying the your new application (i.e prova)